# ASP.net MVC routing parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have route which looks like this:

```
http://localhost:1936/user/someOne/##feed%233dbfc1b3-44b4-42b4-9305-4822ac151527
```

My routes are configured like this:

```
   routes.MapRoute("Profile", "user/{userName}/{treningId}",
            new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", userName = UrlParameter.Optional, treningId = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And Action in my controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string username, string treningId)
    {
      //more code here
    }
```

But I can't get this part: `##feed%233dbfc1b3-44b4-42b4-9305-4822ac151527`, when I debugged code, I saw treningId was null.

My question is how can I get part of URL after ## ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The browser doesn't send the stuff after the first # to the server at all (you can verify this by using the debugger in your browser to inspect the traffic between your browser and the server). That is because [the # (hash) character carries special meaning in HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

Why don't you just

- use regular query parameters (so, something like `http://localhost:1936/user/someOne?myparameter=feed%233dbfc1b3-44b4-42b4-9305-4822ac151527`), or, alternatively,
- choose another delimiter than "##".

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible as hashes are not included in the request; they are reserved for client-side use in URLs (typically to mark a specific location in/portion of a document).

You have two options. Either encode the hash character as `%23`:

```
%23%23feed%233dbfc1b3-44b4-42b4-9305-4822ac151527
```

Or use a different character/route.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your URL written, the browser would not submit any portion of the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) - the hash part of the URL.  As such, your MVC app will never receive the value and thus will always have it as `null`.

To make that value available to MVC, escape the `#` to avoid them marking beginning of  fragment portion of URL.